# How to add local package as requirements in python

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-wheel

I am trying to create a Python *wheel* (`.whl`) of my source code.
My project uses a library which I have downloaded as wheel.

For that, I want to create a *setuptools* `setup.py` script that requires to install the "*outsource*" library first.
The outsource library is in my repository as wheel.

Long story short, I want to create a wheel that could run on standalone environment. The dependency (the library I have downloaded) is provided as wheel.

Flow:

1. Start installing my package
2. Installing the attached package (the library)
3. End installing my package.

So I need a solution for creating a wheel that installs other wheels.

My `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name="my_package_name",
    version=version,
    author_email=",my-name@my-asso.com",
    description=description,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="...",
    python_requires=">=3.6.0",
    cmdclass={
        "clean": CleanCommand,
    },
    #package_dir={"": "package_dir"},
    package_data={"": ["*.pkl", "*.json", "VERSION"]},
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'tests.*')),
    install_requires=requirements,
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
        # Trove classifiers
        # Full list: https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries"
    ],
)
```

---

These are the things I tried to do:

1. Used `requirements.txt` file with the name of the library `PROJECT_NAME==1.1.1` - this works, but it requested from the installer to download the library. and I don't want it to happen. As I mentioned, I want to provide my package to a standalone environment.
2. Used `requirements.txt` file with the relative path to the wheel package `./requirements/PROJECT_NAME-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl`. But it fails with the error:

   > error in my-package setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Parse error at "'./requir'": Expected W:(0-9A-Za-z)

Comment: `pip install` accepts the following args: `-f . —no-index` where `-f` (find links) points to the directory containing wheels for install. In this case, `.` indicates the current directory. This directory will contain the main wheel file and all dependency wheels.  So the install command will be: `pip install my-wheel.whl -f . —no-index`.

Comment: This "outsource" library, is it going to be used at "run-time" or only at "build-time"? Is it a "run-time dependency" or a "build-time dependency"?

Comment: @S3DEV Using your command actually installing the wheel package but doesn't install the depended one.

This dependency is used run time. I am using this library as import statement in my code.

Comment: There isn't any field in `setup` that could provide a local package as requirement instead of online library ?

Comment: _pip_'s default (and expected) behavior is to download from PyPI and only from PyPI. The author (maintainer, publisher) of a library can not force anyone to download from anywhere else. It is up to the user doing the installation to specify where they want to download from (if not PyPI). -- So your best (and only) bet is to clearly document where a user of your library can find your library's dependencies if they are not on PyPI. So that the users of your library can configure their own pip to download from other servers that are not PyPI.

Comment: As far as I know, a project's dependency can be written as a [_PEP 440 "direct reference"_](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#direct-references), but such a project can not be distributed on PyPI. So if it is only for local (internal, private) usage then it should be fine. For example: `install_requires=['SomePrivateLibrary @ https://privateserver.local/path/SomePrivateLibrary.whl']`.